# Remove unknown parameter in initramfs

Tags: initramfs

i was changing the value in the initramfs and i mistype the word..
so every time boot up my ubuntu show "unknown parameter".

how can fix it?how to remove this parameter?

TQ

Comment: This worked for me : [enter link description here](http://askubuntu.com/a/775043/484032)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just boot on a liveCD or liveUSB, mount the partition, and edit the value to a suitable one. Then, reboot on hard disk.

Comment: i had edit the file using vi and remove the line in the .conf file then reboot. everything is ok now..TQ