# Live CD works great, but installed drops to INITRAMFS, kubuntu 16.04 LTS, XFCE

Tags: boot, kubuntu, initramfs

good afternoon,

i recently swapped from Mint to Kubuntu with XFCE.

the Live CD (actually a thumb drive) worked fine, so i went forward with the installation.

on boot, i get dropped to initramfs, with the following error message :

> -missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev ALERT! UUID=XXX does not exist blahblah

where obviously the XXX is the long identifier for my boot drive, and the blahblah is the rest of the message.

after a little research, i assumed that it was simply a boot loader problem, and followed the advice from these three threads :

[Booting to initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744674/booting-to-initramfs)

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

[Help! (initramfs) failed boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654464/help-initramfs-failed-boot)

none of these has fixed my problem... which is a little vexing.

in conclusion, i tried to manually mount & bind the needed folders to the boot drive, i tried the automated boot-repair utility, and i tried simply running FSCK to reassign my boot drive as a boot device... and my problem persists.

further i tried various BIOS settings between UEFI and SATA, etc etc, with no changes. i even used gparted to completely reformat the root drive in case there was some kind of locked partition from the Mint installation.

thankfully i don't have any data on the drive i'm worried about saving, so at least there's no pressure to preserve anything, but i'm completely stumped how to get the computer booting without the Live CD!

any help is appreciated :)

//UPDATE

still searching for an answer. i couldn't find any relevent posts on the "official" ubuntu forum, but i did find this one :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11282550#post11282550

and following the advice, i tried

```
sudo e2fsck /dev/sdX# 
results : 
/dev/sda  "/dev/sda is in use" 
/dev/sda1 "/dev/sda1: clean, xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks" 
/dev/sda2 "no such device or address exists..." 
/dev/sda5 "/dev/sda5 is mounted"
```

needless to say, my sda is not mounted. does anyone know the typical results for e2fsck? i've never used the command and don't know if it's giving me any useful information.

Comment: still searching for an answer...

Comment: Why Kubuntu + XFCE? Surely Xubuntu (which comes with a pre-installed XFCE) would be better? If you use only XFCE and no KDE apps (not KDE desktop environment, the KDE apps), Xubuntu would be better (lighter, less bloat etc.)

Comment: OP decided to [reinstall \[XK\]ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/778317/175814)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my Kubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 yesterday. After few hours, I get to initramfs, I tried some few things and none of them worked. Finally I started my system with Live Linux USB and I tried this:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sda1
```

I was asked questions and I just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (many times) until the end and restart my system. You can find the source at [Help! (initramfs) failed boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654464/help-initramfs-failed-boot).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem today after resume from hibernation. I really don't know why this happens with Kubuntu 16.04 so much. This is what I got on live USB (Kubuntu 16.04)[image] and I just hit Enter until the end. This is a bit embarrassing because I most have live USB around. Do someone knows how to solve definitely this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i finally gave up, and installed 16.04 **X**ubuntu... and then after that booted properly, plugged my 16.04 **K**ubuntu live-disk and opted for the "Delete and install without reformating".

that way the *correct* boot structure that **X**ubuntu installed was left in place, but i could still use the OS that i wanted.

works like a champ since then.

judging from the lack of answers for this problem, i'm thinking it might be a very limited incompatibility with certain hard drives? i'm using a Samsung SSD, what about you guys/galls?